# Tethering HC3.2 with Windows Mobile

Tags: wifi-tethering, 3.2-honeycomb, windows-mobile, acer-iconia-a500, htc-hd2

I bought a non-3G tablet because I already have a 3G phone with tethering function: HTC HD2 with stock WM6.5.

When I enable "Wi-Fi Router" program from WM I successfully create the `Aldaris` network (yes, [that](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Aldaris) one!) that any Windows and Linux laptop can see.

But not my Iconia Tab!!!

Any ideas on how to use a tethered wifi from HC3.2? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems due to a limitation in the OS (Android I mean) that hides (why the hell??!?!?) ad hoc networks like HD2 creates. Solution is posted on http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1060909 and is now working!

Comment: It's not really "hiding" it, per say - Android can't connect to ad-hoc networks out of the box. Since it can't connect, it doesn't show as part of the scan for access points.

Comment: I'm not an expert in level-2 networking, but I don't think connecting to an adhoc network is very different from connecting to an infrastructure, in terms of 802.11 protocol. Maybe I'm wrong and just Android designers didn't feel the need to connect to adhoc nets from tablets/phones and *forgot* to tell developers to implement it. +1 to XDA

Comment: I have no idea how different it is either, but it's been a long-standing ticket [on their issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82). For whatever reason, they've chosen not to officially support it up to this point, so you have no choice but to use modified `wpa_supplicant` files (as you found on XDA).